# Smarty getting page content

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I need to edit a page on prestashop, I've found that code

```
 <ul id="idTab2" class="bullet">{$agencies->content}</ul>
```

And where should i search for that `$agencies` variable ? 
I have found the text which is being displayed into that place in CMS. 
However I'd that variable need to be define somewhere, am I right ? Anyone knows where should i search for that ? I'm new to prestashop.

Why am i asking for this ?  I need to add another page for example

```
<ul id="idTab2" class="bullet">{$test->content}</ul>
```

- but I can't just simply add another page called `test`.

Answer (score 2):

The `{$agencies}` variable is being set in a object derived from either the `Controller` or `Module` classes but to be honest it looks like you're working with code that has been customised (via a class override or a module) making it impossible to provide a definitive answer to your question without knowing more detail.

If you can locate the term 'agencies' in a file located under `\controllers`, `\modules` or `\override` in your installation, then you will be closer to finding your answer. It will be contained in a function call similar to:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('agencies' , [some-variable]);
```

Note that the parameters to the function may also be passed as an array for multiple assignments.

Comment: Thank you, however I think I had looked into every single file already, but maybe I missed something ;)

Comment: So I have found something like that `'agencies' => $this->cmsa,` now shall I search for `cmsa` ?